# Python Script from Postman not working

Tags: python, postman

I have bought a little wifi relay module - though it is in Chinese which I do not read I have worked out how to open and close the relay from the buttons on the home page on the embedded web server.

I then used postman interceptor to capture the 'open' and 'close' actions, and I can now click the 'post' button to make the action happen.

However the 'generate code' python script doesn't work, and from my limited understanding doesn't have the right info.

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.4.1/"

payload = ""
headers = {
    'origin': "http://192.168.4.1",
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    'dnt': "1",
    'referer': "http://192.168.4.1/",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "bece04e7-ee50-3764-ca50-e86d07ebc0f3"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

The output when I select HTTP instead of Python Requests is

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Origin: http://192.168.4.1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: http://192.168.4.1/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0bd42b4f-067d-b5be-dd1c-b7e689196043

open_relay=%EF%BF%BD%F2%BF%AA%BC%CC%B5%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD
```

Could someone suggest how to modify the Python to correctly send the POST which works correctly from with Postman itself ?

Comment: I believe you need to put `open_relay=%EF%BF%BD%F2%BF%AA%BC%CC%B5%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD` in the `payload` variable in your python code.

Comment: Note, that data appears to be url-quoted values encoded in GB-2312.

Comment: Yes, pasting that text into the payload variable worked - thanks very much - I'm a complete newb to SO - how do I mark the question answered, give kudos etc ?

Comment: @point5Clue great, happy to help! (and welcome to SO!) I've moved my comment to an answer so that you can click the check mark to mark as the accepted answer (and upvote, if you wish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python code is missing the POST data which contains the command to the piece of equipment, which is listed at the bottom of the http request.

Put `open_relay=%EF%BF%BD%F2%BF%AA%BC%CC%B5%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD` into the `payload` variable in the python code:

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.4.1/"

payload = "open_relay=%EF%BF%BD%F2%BF%AA%BC%CC%B5%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD"
headers = {
  'origin': "http://192.168.4.1",
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
  'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36",
  'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  'dnt': "1",
  'referer': "http://192.168.4.1/",
  'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
  'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  'cache-control': "no-cache",
  'postman-token': "bece04e7-ee50-3764-ca50-e86d07ebc0f3"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: In fact, I could strip out all the header info and remove the 'headers=...' part, and it still works fine - thanks again.